# Do herbaceous plants have woody parts?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, plant-perception

Do herbaceous plants, especially perennial plants have woody parts, like woody stem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pasting the Q in google gives wiki as first hit - answer is in second line of wiki article.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, no. An herbaceous plant is defined as a plant that has [no woody parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbaceous_plant). Herbaceous perennials die down to the roots at the end of the year and then sprout up again at the start of the next growing season, but they do not have woody parts. A plant that is small and herblike but has woody parts may be called a [subshrub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subshrub).

Comment: a subshrub :) that's cool

Comment: '"Subshrub" is often used interchangeably with "bush".' TIL bush isn't a synonym for shrub!

Comment: This isn't entirely true since the OP is asking for woody parts (not only above-ground parts), and perennial herbaceous plants can have "woody" roots (depending on how you define woody). See e.g. [herbchronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbchronology) for age determination of perennial herbs.